# General error: 1005 Can't create table errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, database, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.4

> Blockquote
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `gps`.`#sql-9e4_161` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `receivers` add constraint 
>     `receivers_hospital_id_foreign` foreign key (`hospital_id`) references `hospitals` (`id`))

```
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamp('dob');
        $table->string('profile_image');
        $table->string('profession')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('weight');
        $table->string('message');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

    });


{
    Schema::create('receivers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('member_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('hospital_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members');
        $table->foreign('hospital_id')->references('id')->on('hospitals');
    });


{
    Schema::create('hospitals', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('h_name');
        $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('donate_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
        $table->foreign('donate_id')->references('id')->on('donates');


    });


{
    Schema::create('donates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('date');

        $table->date('last_bleed');
        $table->string('quantity');
        $table->string('comments');
        $table->integer('blood_group_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('member_id')->unsigned()->index();

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->foreign('blood_group_id')->references('id')-
                             >on('blood_groups');
        $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```

Comment: Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('hospital_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('receiver_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('hospital_id')->references('id')->on('hospitals');
            $table->foreign('receiver_id')->references('id')->on('receivers');
        });
Ya country ka table ha

Comment: please send your whole migration file, it's unspecific right now

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `member`, `blood_groups` table to fully check everything.

Check that

1) All the foreign keys should match the type of primary key they match.
For example, if you use `increments` for PK make sure that FK has type of `unsignedInteger`

2) Make sure the order is right. You can't create the foreign key if you don't have a table. For the code, I see it should be something like

Also, I found that in the `hospitals` table you have FK (`country_id`) to `countries` table and in the `countries` table you have FK (`hospital_id`) to `hospitals` table. You can't do like that, there should only be one of then (probably `country_id`). The reason why is because (I don't know which of those are created first, so let say it's `hospitals`) when you create `hospitals`, you try to make FK to the table that doesn't exists.